# Arduino yum hangs on bootup when using Firmata

Tags: arduino, arduino-yun

I am using the StandardFirmata on a new Yun.

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/edgarsilva/e73c15a019396d6aaef2/raw/b00e100f1551d87e30f49e5ac98517370e699ee2/StandardFirmataForATH0.ino

Everything works great while I am in Linux.
But as soon as I reboot, the Yun linux will not come up (seems like networking doesn't come up).

I am using the latest Yun build.

UT, the problem is that after a reboot, the device will not boot Linux (maybe Linux interfaces are down).

for whatever reason, these lines are causing the problem:

Serial1.begin(57600); // Set the baud.
Firmata.begin(Serial1);

but if I do it like the original file:

Firmata.begin(57600);

the Linux works fine on boot, but I can't get Firmata to work if I take that line...
so it's a catch 22..

PLEASE HELP, I have already worked on this for 2 days and can't find a solution on google,

Thanks for reading,

Sean.

Answer (score 0):

FIXED:

yes I had the same issue..

using node.js and Firmata.

FIXED:

in /usr/lib/node_modules/firmata/lib/firmata.js edit the line

```
if(typeof port === 'object'){
    this.sp = port;
} else {
    this.sp = new SerialPort(port, {
        baudrate: XXXX,
        buffersize: 1

    });
}
```

and set XXXX to be 9600

and in StandardFirmata set the same:

Serial1.begin(9600); // Set the baud.

now Node.js speaks to Firmata no problem!!!!!!!

hope this helps someone get their Arduino Yun to speak to Firmata / Cyclon.js